# SSH remote connection to server with vscromium

Tags: linux, macos, visual-studio-code, ssh, vscodium

Hello i like to change to VSCodium with linux but i have a problem, in VSCODE i use remote-ssh and works fine, but this same package in VSCodium doesn't work.

It ask me password and after i have a error:

```
[20:38:29.280] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+1.1.1.1", attempt 5, (Reconnection)
[20:38:29.281] SSH Resolver called for host: 1.1.1.1
[20:38:29.282] Setting up SSH remote "1.1.1.1"
[20:38:29.283] Acquiring local install lock: /var/folders/bz/gzbhhfv928n_jdqsk23ttycm0000gn/T/vscode-remote-ssh-eb13906b-install.lock
[20:38:29.283] Looking for existing server data file at /Users/XXXXXXXXXX/Library/Application Support/VSCodium/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-eb13906b-cea9d1a4b17966719d8c5f3cdd914480f7cec47c-0.87.2022090715/data.json
[20:38:29.284] Using commit id "cea9d1a4b17966719d8c5f3cdd914480f7cec47c" and quality "stable" for server
[20:38:29.286] Install and start server if needed
[20:38:29.291] askpass server listening on /var/folders/bz/gzbhhfv928n_jdqsk23ttycm0000gn/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-da57138f4d7832fc3734ad7a50dc225ccbef89e5.sock
[20:38:29.291] Spawning local server with {"serverId":5,"ipcHandlePath":"/var/folders/bz/gzbhhfv928n_jdqsk23ttycm0000gn/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-de457e3bd9a608cfdd3faf37d5903491af5d4969.sock","sshCommand":"ssh","sshArgs":["-v","-T","-D","52249","-o","ConnectTimeout=15","1.1.1.1"],"serverDataFolderName":".vscodium-server","dataFilePath":"/Users/XXXXXXXXXX/Library/Application Support/VSCodium/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-eb13906b-cea9d1a4b17966719d8c5f3cdd914480f7cec47c-0.87.2022090715/data.json"}
[20:38:29.291] Local server env: {"SSH_AUTH_SOCK":"/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.DkNdtZMLnV/Listeners","SHELL":"/bin/zsh","DISPLAY":"1","ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE":"1","SSH_ASKPASS":"/Users/XXXXXXXXXX/.vscode-oss/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.87.2022090715/out/local-server/askpass.sh","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_NODE":"/Applications/VSCodium.app/Contents/Frameworks/VSCodium Helper.app/Contents/MacOS/VSCodium Helper","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_EXTRA_ARGS":"--ms-enable-electron-run-as-node","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_MAIN":"/Users/XXXXXXXXXX/.vscode-oss/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.87.2022090715/out/askpass-main.js","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_HANDLE":"/var/folders/bz/gzbhhfv928n_jdqsk23ttycm0000gn/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-da57138f4d7832fc3734ad7a50dc225ccbef89e5.sock"}
[20:38:29.292] Spawned 11544
[20:38:29.437] > local-server-5> Spawned ssh, pid=11548
[20:38:29.440] stderr> OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
[20:38:29.490] stderr> ssh: connect to host 1.1.1.1 port 22: Connection refused
[20:38:29.492] > local-server-5> ssh child died, shutting down
[20:38:29.496] Local server exit: 0
[20:38:29.497] Received install output: local-server-5> Spawned ssh, pid=11548
OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
ssh: connect to host 1.1.1.1 port 22: Connection refused
local-server-5> ssh child died, shutting down

[20:38:29.497] Failed to parse remote port from server output
[20:38:29.497] Resolver error: Error: 
    at g.Create (/Users/XXXXXXXXXX/.vscode-oss/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.87.2022090715/out/extension.js:1:583821)
    at t.handleInstallOutput (/Users/XXXXXXXXXX/.vscode-oss/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.87.2022090715/out/extension.js:1:582473)
    at Object.e [as tryInstallWithLocalServer] (/Users/XXXXXXXXXX/.vscode-oss/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.87.2022090715/out/extension.js:1:622972)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async /Users/XXXXXXXXXX/.vscode-oss/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.87.2022090715/out/extension.js:1:642100
    at async t.withShowDetailsEvent (/Users/XXXXXXXXXX/.vscode-oss/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.87.2022090715/out/extension.js:1:645820)
    at async /Users/XXXXXXXXXX/.vscode-oss/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.87.2022090715/out/extension.js:1:621444
    at async T (/Users/XXXXXXXXXX/.vscode-oss/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.87.2022090715/out/extension.js:1:617950)
    at async t.resolveWithLocalServer (/Users/XXXXXXXXXX/.vscode-oss/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.87.2022090715/out/extension.js:1:621059)
    at async t.resolve (/Users/XXXXXXXXXX/.vscode-oss/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.87.2022090715/out/extension.js:1:643428)
    at async /Users/XXXXXXXXXX/.vscode-oss/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.87.2022090715/out/extension.js:1:722225
[20:38:29.499] ------
```

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's remote extensions won't work with VSCodium because Microsoft restricted them to only work in VS Code. Their licenses also don't permit any usage in any editor other than Visual Studio family products. More context: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=31714082